# How to iterate through a list of tuples and checking each list for a specific order

Tags: python, list, iteration

I need some help in determining how to get the relevant numbers inside a list of tuples.
I cannot figure out how to structure the nested statements to get the required results.

To explain it better:

I have a list of tuples as follows and they are all ready sorted smallest value to largest value:

```
my_list = [(1,2,3,4,5),(1,2,3,4,6),(1,2,3,4,7),(2,3,4,5,6),(2,3,4,5,7)]
```

So I need to iterate through each value inside each tuple and print the tuple if the values inside the tuple follows the previous number in the same tuple.

So the list that should be printed is `[(1,2,3,4,5),(2,3,4,5,6)]` as the numbers follow on each other where as the rest of the values in the other tuples jump a number from time to time. I will be assigning the `new_list` of numbers following each other in a new list and removing those numbers from a another list I have.

So the code I think should be as follows if someone can possibly shed some light on my problem or possibly make any suggestions:

```
new_list = []
for a in my_list: #iterate through the lists
  if i in a == ??(i-1) #iterate through each value in the list and check it against the number before it excluding the first iteration of i which will have no number before it.
      print(list if the numbers follow on each other)
      new_list.append(a)
```

Comment: At the moment I have no idea how to go about even structuring the code to get the required results or if it is even possible to achieve it.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it with a couple of helper functions and a list comprehension:

```py
# Find the difference between each consecutive element. Note skip the element at position 0 as there is nothing before it to 'diff' against
def diff(my_list):
     return [item - my_list[idx - 1] for idx, item in enumerate(my_list) if idx > 0]

# The items of a list are consecutive if all the elements of the diff list are 1
def is_consecutive(my_list):
     return all(item == 1 for item in diff(my_list))

# This is a basic filtering list comprehension based on the function we just defined
new_list = [my_tuple for my_tuple in my_list if is_consecutive(my_tuple)]
```

These sorts of operations are built into numpy, have you considered if it's worth your while using it?

Comment: Thanks, have never used it before, still relatively new to coding. But will look into it just now.

Comment: this is a good answer. this will fun faster than iterating, and it doesn't require to install extra libraries (as said, consider installing numpy if you do this kind of things often in your program)

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so I was able to get the following, seems like I did not have to iterate through the tuple inside the list , instead I just called the index position and referenced it to the next index position - 1 as it is all int class:

Been struggling with it for days, couldn't believe it was so simple think it was more a problem about my brain being stuck to solve the problem than actually coding it out.

Please feel free to give me some suggestions to clean up the code a bit?

```
new_list = []
for a in my_list:
    if a[0] == a[1] -1 and a[1] == a[2] -1 and a[2] == a[3] -1 and a[3] == a[4] -1:
        new_list.append(a)
```

Comment: look how many times you have typed out the pattern `a[n] == a[n+2] -1` - this should indicate to you that you can refactor it to reduce your repeated code (i.e. you need an inner loop, preferably refactored out to a separate function). Also, it could help you generalize should your tuples change length from 5 elements. Lastly, your original idea of appending to a list is much more useful than just printing it as I'm sure you'll want to work more with the result.

Comment: Thanks, just edited it to append the list. Copied my testing code from my Jupyter notebook and forgot to add the append line in there.

Still new with coding so not sure how to simplify it yet. If you don't mind, I would appreciate it if you could give me an example for the inner for loop?